# Forcing subclasses to have a particular factory method or constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, factory-method

I am 70% confident that this is impossible, but is there a way to make sure that subclasses have a particular constructor or factory method?

In this case, I am trying to create a `StringSerializable` that would require subclasses to have the following methods

- `toString`, which converts the object to a `String`.
- `fromString`, which gets an instance from a `String`.

Obviously, in the first case, I can just make `toString` abstract. On the other hand, having a  nonstatic `fromString` seems to be problematic. However, I can't create an abstract static method. I also do not think that a constructor is entirely appropriate.

Comment: You could use reflection, in the constructor.

Comment: @immibis I've heard that that can be unsafe because sometimes reflection doesn't work.

Comment: also reflection is very slow and should be avoided in production code in general afaik

Comment: THis is very doable with reflections.  WHy is having a nonstatic fromString seems to be problematic?

Comment: It is never the case that "reflection does not work". However, it is true that it is difficult to do correctly, so it should be the last option.

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 that is no true.  You can have reflections in production code, just do all the expensive reflection stuff at startup.

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 that penalty is minimal these days except perhaps embedded work.

Comment: OK, so what you are saying is have a 0 arg constructor, and a nonstatic `fromString`, then use a general factory method in the superclass that gets an instance and then calls `fromString`.

Comment: Where do you want to do this validation check, e.g. like for a given class at a specific point or for all subclasses at startup or validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct; it's impossible to force it at compile time. There are various tricks you could do at runtime (such as using reflection in tests), but that's about it.

But ask yourself: *why* do you want to require that? You can't dynamically invoke a static method or constructor (except through reflection), so how exactly would you use those required factories, if you had them?

If it's just for consistency in the code (which is a good thing!), then you'll just have to ensure that consistency as you develop the code base. A comment in the base class can go a long way here, as can code reviews and other "soft" techniques.

If you plan to use the factories in reflection, then similar reflection can be used in tests to make sure that each subclass has the bits it needs.

Another option is to create a non-static factory:

```
public interface FooMaker() {
    Foo create(String arg);
}
```

... and use that, rather than a static `fromString` method.

There again you have the same problem of "how do I ensure that every subclass has a `FooMaker` implementation?" and again I would say that you shouldn't worry about that. If you make the `FooMaker` the "starting point" of your code, rather than the subclasses, then it doesn't matter what the subclasses are doing; all that matters is that your `FooMaker`s give you a way of going from string to `Foo`s, and each `Foo` has a way of going back to a string.

Comment: It is basically just for code consistency. What I was doing before was requiring a nonstatic factory but in practice just using to reference a static factory.

Answer (score 0):

the following code does ensure that every subclass needs to implement the static method, if the subclass does not implement the method it will fail when classes are constructed, as close as you can get to a compile time error, but not at compile time

the exception thrown is very clear and the programm will instantly fail when started

```
public abstract class Base {
   static Functional test;

   static {
      if(test == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You need to provide an implementation for the implemntMe method in class base");
      }
   }

   private interface Functional {
      Base implementMe(int whatever, boolean anotherParameter);
   }

   public static void main(final String[] args) {

   }
```

}

the private interface construct ensures that only lambdas can be used to implement the method

a subclass would have to look like this

```
public SubClass extends Base {
   static {
      test = (int whatever, boolean anotherParameter) -> {
         Subclass tmp = new Subclass();
         //construct object
         tmp.setWhatever(whatever);
         return tmp;
      }
   }
}
```

lamdas are like inline methods that implement a functional interface, an interface which has only one abstract method

you can also declare the interface publicly at any other place and implement it with an anonymous inner class,
but my way makes sure that programers have to copy and paste code to reuse it,
or need to copy the object of Functional from another class

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with this type of mixing of static and inner. I was wondering if you could demonstrate what the subclass would have to do?